# How to check for quotations in swift 4?

Tags: swift, swift4

I am trying to check for string if it contains a single quotation or a double quotation

I tried using the following code but when I test and enter in the text field a single or double quotation , it passes as if there is no quotation.

```
var usernameSQL = username.text?.contains("\'") as! Bool || username.text?.contains("\"") as! Bool

guard !usernameSQL else {
            let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Invlalid symbols", message: "(') and (\") symbols are not allowed", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

            self.show(alertVC, sender: nil)
            return
        }

print("passed")
```

What I get is "passed" being printed instead of getting alert "Invalid symbols".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you print `username.text`? Could it be that it has in fact `’` or `‘` (for the single quote samples)?

Comment: You should unwrap `username.text` and reuse it, instead of force casting function results from `Bool?` to `Bool`. For `UITextField`/`UITextView` `.text` it won't crash your app, but you should not force everything.

Comment: @Larme YEAAAH! it showed a different character. The input was `’` and the one I was checking for was `'`. However now I face a problem that if `’` is the first character it is not checked.

Comment: So what about the reverse, what are the allowed characters? Why only single quote/double quotes are not allowed?

Comment: @Larme Actually all other characters are allowed. Only quotations are not allowed for security reasons.

Comment: @AshishKakkad The problem is not with displaying the alert , the problem is that the else part of the guard is not entered and the rest of code after guard code is executed.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid injection attack by disallowing some characters in your UI then you are doing it wrong. Your backend could still be attacked by using APIs directly. You should use proper input sanitization on your backend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating things.

You can easily achieve the same result with this small refactor.

```
if let textValue = username.text {
    if textValue.contains("\'") || textValue.contains("\"") {
        print("Show Alert")
    } else {
        print("Passed")
    }
} else {
    print("username.text is nil do something or just ignore")
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is correct although I would argue that it's safer to check for allowed characters instead of disabling some special ones.

Comment: @Sulthan according to OP "all other characters are allowed. Only quotations are not allowed for security reasons."

Comment: Then it's trying to fix injection attacks by a bad hack instead of using proper input sanitization...

Answer (score 0):

A smarter solution is to use `CharacterSet` and `rangeOfCharacter(from:`. The benefit is the optional doesn't need to be unwrapped.

If there are no quotes the expression returns `nil` and passes the `guard`.

```
let quoteSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\'\"")
guard username.text?.rangeOfCharacter(from: quoteSet) == nil else { ...
```

However I would take Larme's advice and create the character set with the **allowed** characters.